# Php save 4 data to mysql db instead of 2 in my sms gateway api

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a php sms API which sent sms (not email) to my registered user. So in my html form there is a option to send sms by uploading a file where all contact exist.  After successfully sent sms I saved it to mysql db.

Well, everything is ok now but in my .txt file (**Sending sms by uploading .txt file**) there is 2 contact exist. So it must saved 2 data in my db table. But unfortunately it's saved 4 data into db. I can't understand where is the problem. Can you please  tell me why it's saved 4 data ?

**My php code:**

```
$file_handle = fopen("$file", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
$line_of_text[0]=$line_of_text[0];       
$obj = new Sender("websms.dnstel.com","my port","my username","my password","$sender", "$msg",    
$line_of_text[0],"2","1"); 
$obj->Submit();     
$success_number[]=$line_of_text[0];

//saved sms to db
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_sent_sms VALUES('', '$line_of_text[0]', '$msg', '', '',   
'$length', '$type', '$sender', '$current_date', '$ip' )");
}
echo "<div class='success'>Successfully sent your message to " . implode(',',$success_number) ." 
Thank You.</div>";
fclose($file_handle);
```

**.txt file**

```
8801674455258
8801674455852
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you investigate what kind of data is stored inside the database? Does it save the same number twice?

Comment: `$line_of_text[0]=$line_of_text[0];` What a useless line.

Comment: @Sven yes i investigate this. It's save 4 data to db where 2 row has completed data and another 2 row has all data except mobile number. The mobile number field is empty.

Comment: Check in the file whether you have only 2 lines or empty lines at the end or check if condition in while loop like if (!empty($success_number)) { }

Comment: Use MySQLi and bind your variables, use Exceptions, objects and proper validation. Over and over again same issues.. I'd insert the whole textfile first into the db, and have a column which indicates the status of the sms; instead of first sending sms and then inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while statement to:

```
while(($line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0)) !== FALSE)
```

and remove:

```
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
```

Comment: i changed you code but now it's sent 1 sms but saved 2 row in the db where last row has empty number.

Comment: you removed the `$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);` right?

Comment: No I don't remove it.

Comment: Well, that would likely be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you check for `!feof($file_handle)` and if the file has empty spaces then the condition becomes valid. If you use `fgetcsv($file_handle)` it will get the row from csv/text as a `NULL` if empty, or values if valid in array format from where you can process the results.

So your code should look like this,

```
while (($line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle,1024)) && $line_of_text[0])
{      
  //$obj = new Sender("websms.dnstel.com","my port","my username","my password","$sender", "$msg", $line_of_text[0],"2","1"); 
  //$obj->Submit();     
  //$success_number[]=$line_of_text[0];

  //saved sms to db
  $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_sent_sms VALUES('', '$line_of_text[0]', '$msg', '', '','$length', '$type', '$sender', '$current_date', '$ip' )");
}
```

Comment: It's sending toooooo much sms.. :(

Comment: You lost my 400 sms. :( :(

Comment: OOps I am sorry!! Check my edit now.. and comment out the sms part and see if it is updating the database only twice

Comment: Not it's not sending any sms.

Comment: Thanks for you help Deepark. But your code is not safe for me. I lost again.

Comment: I asked you to comment the sms part did you do that ? and now check your database if its updated..